# keep input state after url redirect

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

I am trying to mimic the behaviour that certain websites such as netflix display when typing in its search bar. The input element remains active whilst redirected to a url with a query parameter containing the input value like so:
[toggle of netflix's searchbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SITAD.gif)

any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: It's not redirecting. Even if the URL seems like being manipulated, it's just javascript.

Comment: thanks, this was very helpful despite being a direct answer; ended up using javascripts history.pushState to manipulate the url without refreshing the page

Comment: I suggest that you answer your own question since you found a solution. Further, you can accept your answer to declare that the question had been answered.

Answer (score 0):

So, basically you need to call the search function (let's say it returns the movies with matching keyword) every time the user presses the key. This can be achieved by using `event handlers` such as `onkeyup` see [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onkeyup).

The `search` function :-

```
<input type = 'text'  onkeyup = 'searchMovies(this.value)' placeholder = 'Search'/>`

<script>
  function searchMovies(key) {
    // Search logic goes here
    console.log(key);
}
</script>
```

Comment: I don't think this is answers the OP question. Consider adding some more context to what "the search function" would be

Comment: Added @AramBecker

Comment: I think what the op is asking is more in the direction of how to "simulate" a page reload when searching for things. As in, how would you catch the submit of the search firm and replace the results without reloading the page